# AICS Test Report for Android device

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I am looking for steps to generate AICS Test report for my android device.

I was able to cross compile the sdk code for using Android ndk.
Is there any application or steps that can help me to generate the AICS report.

We are looking for more information on how to move forward once SDK Compilation for Android is successful. How to test whether the compilation of sdk is successful or not? Is there any android sample code which we can try to ensure the connection to Azure IOT Hub is successful and are able to transfer the sensor data to IOT Hub.

Please guide.

Comment: Can you add more details regarding your query?

Comment: @Ashok, have updated the querry.